# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v2.train' has no attribute 'get_or_create_global_step'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have this line of code as part of a function:

```
global_step = tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()
```

An this is the error I'm getting:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-e0d01fc93072> in <module>()
    131     summary_writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(log_path, flush_millis=10000)
    132     summary_writer.set_as_default()
--> 133     global_step = tf.get_or_create_global_step()
    134 
    135     # Load the dataset

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_or_create_global_step'
```

I get that this function is deprecated but I couldn't figure out how to make the necessary adjustments and the migration guide wasn't very clear.

This is the entirety of my code:

```
# Make directories for this run
time_string = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
model_path = os.path.join(model_path, time_string)
results_path = os.path.join(results_path, time_string)
safe_makedirs(model_path)
safe_makedirs(results_path)

# Initialise logging
log_path = os.path.join('logs', exp_name, time_string)
summary_writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(log_path, flush_millis=10000)
summary_writer.set_as_default()
global_step = tf.train.get_or_create_global_step() <- This is the line.

# Load the dataset
(train_images, _), (test_images, _) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
train_images = train_images.reshape(train_images.shape[0], raw_size, raw_size, channels)

# Add noise for condition input
train_inputs = add_gaussian_noise(train_images, stdev=0.2, data_range=(0, 255)).astype('float32')
train_inputs = normalise(train_inputs, (-1, 1), (0, 255))
train_images = normalise(train_images, (-1, 1), (0, 255))
train_labels = train_images.astype('float32')

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_inputs, train_labels)).shuffle(buffer_size).batch(batch_size)

# Test set
test_images = test_images.reshape(test_images.shape[0], raw_size, raw_size, channels)
test_inputs = add_gaussian_noise(test_images, stdev=0.2, data_range=(0, 255)).astype('float32')
test_inputs = normalise(test_inputs, (-1, 1), (0, 255))
test_images = normalise(test_images, (-1, 1), (0, 255))
test_labels = test_images.astype('float32')

# Set up some random (but consistent) test cases to monitor
num_examples_to_generate = 16
random_indices = np.random.choice(np.arange(test_inputs.shape[0]), num_examples_to_generate,replace=False)
selected_inputs = test_inputs[random_indices]
selected_labels = test_labels[random_indices]

# Set up the models for training
generator = make_generator_model_small()
discriminator = make_discriminator_model()

generator_optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
discriminator_optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)

checkpoint_prefix = os.path.join(model_path, "ckpt")
checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint(generator_optimizer=generator_optimizer, discriminator_optimizer=discriminator_optimizer, generator=generator, discriminator=discriminator)

generate_and_save_images(None, 0, selected_inputs, selected_labels)  # baseline
print("\nTraining...\n")

# Compile training function into a callable TensorFlow graph (speeds up execution)
train_step = tf.contrib.eager.defun(train_step)
train(train_dataset, max_epoch)
print("\nTraining done\n")
```

Comment: Which version of TF are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 2.8.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i gathered in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.8.1/tensorflow/python/training/training_util.py, and https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/0ea7b2bcc2f553b06859b7cbf6962dfc340c868d,
it seems that you should be calling:

```
global_step = tf.training_util.get_or_create_global_step()
```

Although there's also this:

```
global_step = tf.compat.v1.train.get_or_create_global_step()
```

(this is from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/9e2ac684a641b236431d0602b80fc9391dd565c0/tensorflow/examples/speech_commands/train.py#L187)

Though I would hazard a guess that since this is with the `compat.v1.train` module, and you're using the 2.0
version,  you're probably good with going with the `tf.training_util.get_or_create_global_step()`.

But, there's a note in the comment for the `get_or_create_global_step()` [https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/training_util.py#L267], and I quote:

> With the deprecation of global graphs, TF no longer tracks variables in
> collections. In other words, there are no global variables in TF2. Thus, the
> global step functions have been removed  (`get_or_create_global_step`,
> `create_global_step`, `get_global_step`) . You have two options for migrating:
>
> 1. Create a Keras optimizer, which generates an `iterations` variable. This
>    variable is automatically incremented when calling `apply_gradients`.
> 2. Manually create and increment a `tf.Variable`.